# Highstock - Creating an OHLC graph by csv created using php

Tags: php, javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm having some problems with importing the csv in order to get the highstock graph.
I'm using the same code as the ohlc example (which works fine locally) but with another CSV which is created on my localhost by php.

PHP to get the CSV

```
<?PHP

// Declare the new variable as an array
$arrCSV = array();

// Open the CSV file
if (($handle = fopen("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=7&e=7&f=2012&g=d&a=8&b=7&c=1984&ignore=.csv", "r")) !==FALSE)
{

// Set the parent array key to 0
$key = 0;
// While there is data available loop through unlimited times (0) using separator (,)
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {

    // Count the total keys in each row
    $c = count($data);
    //print  $c . "<BR>"; // <------ 7 o numero de colunas

    //Populate the array
    If ($key != 0) {
        $arrCSV[$key-1][0] = strtotime($data[0]); //Time
        $arrCSV[$key-1][1] = $data[1];            //Open
        $arrCSV[$key-1][2] = $data[2];            //High
        $arrCSV[$key-1][3] = $data[3];            //Low
        $arrCSV[$key-1][4] = $data[6];            //Adj Close
        $arrCSV[$key-1][5] = $data[5];            //Volume
    }

    $key++;
} // end while

$keymax = $key;

// Close the CSV file
fclose($handle);
} // end if

print "?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */<BR>";
echo json_encode($arrCSV,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
print ");";

?>
```

Code to import and create the graph:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Highstock Example</title>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://localhost/teste03.php', function(data) {

      // create the chart
      chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
         chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
         },

         rangeSelector : {
            selected : 2
         },

         title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
         },

         series : [{
            type : 'ohlc',
            name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data : data,
            dataGrouping : {
               units : [[
                  'week', // unit name
                  [1] // allowed multiples
               ], [
                  'month', 
                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
               ]]
            }
         }]
      });
   });
});

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
<script src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the end it just get me a blank page...
Is this caused by being using localhost? The order of the array (descendent instead of ascendent)?

Help?

Update: json_encode added but still doesn't work.

Comment: Just to add more info, currently the php is printing the following csv: [[1344290400,622.77,625,618.04,618.26,10373100],[1344204000,617.29,624.87,615.26,619.89,10789400], (...) ]]

Comment: there it is, the timestamps are not in ascending order. Check edited answer below

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Meanwhile after some tests with consolo.log the issue seems to be on the getJSON. It runs, at least on the console it says: [12:16:26.572] GET http://(..)teste05.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2766ms] but it doesn't run since I have added a console.log in there, never receiving any output.

Comment: So your ajax call is failing you mean. how are you accessing your current page? It it also with localhost? Make sure you are not making a cross domain request.
Are you aware about cross domain ajax calls? If not see this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FURTHER EDITED**
Seems that you might have ajax issues, try doing an isolated test by

Using the `SimpleTest.php` (refer **OLD** section for code) and hosting it on the same server as your current `teste03.php`, and access the chart from it

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost/SimpleTest.php', function(data) {
 ...
 }
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
// $.getJSON('http://localhost/teste03.php', function(data) {
   var data= [[1000000,1,2,3,4],[2000000,3,2,3,4],[1000000,1,2,3,4]];
  // create the chart
  chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
   ...
```

If any of the above approaches work, means that you have an ajax issue and not a highcharts issue.

**EDITED** (based on your comment about the json that was returned)

The timestamp values in the data need to be in ascending order. From your following json

```
 [[1344290400,622.77,625,618.04,618.26,10373100],[1344204000,617.29,624.87,615.26‌​,619.89,10789400]
```

1344290400>1344204000 hence wont work.

**OLD**
use the [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method for the json formation.
What you need to pass to it is, an array of array where the outer array is of the size same as the number of rows in the CSV, and each element of this outer array is another array with 5 elements, viz. timestamp, open, high, low, close.

`SimpleTest.php`:

```
<?php
  // JSON header
  header('Content-type: application/json');

  // Do not cache the response
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');  

  // Parse CSV, and populate the 5 arrays viz. $timeStamp, $open, $high, $low, $close
  $count=3;
  $timeStamp=array(1000000,2000000,3000000); // In ascending order of time
  $open=array(5,10,15);
  $high=array(10,15,20);
  $low=array(0,5,10);
  $close=array(8,12,18);

  $dataArray=array();   // Outer array of array
  
  for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ){
     // push an array into $dataArray for each data group
     $dataArray[] = array($timeStamp[$i], $open[$i], $high[$i], $low[$i],$close[$i]);
  }

  echo json_encode($dataArray); // Encode php array of array into json and echo/print it to output
?>
```

Looking at your code, i think you can tweak you $arrCSV to transform into the required array.

Comment: HI, thanks for the answear but it still doesn't work. I have usedd json_encode and even managed to take out the quotation marks on the variables with JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK achieving more or less the same php that I had before. I will update my question to add those modifications.

Comment: You don't need `print "?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */<BR>";` or `print ");";`
around the json_encode

Comment: In the simplest case, could you host the above php that i have posted as a different `simpleAjaxTest.php` file and try accessing that from the chart like `$.getJSON('http://localhost/simpleAjaxTest.php'...` and see if that works, if not than you have an ajax problem in hand rather than a highchart issue, alternate way to do this test would be replace the ajax call entirely with hard coded json data that you are expecting

Comment: Cool, but can you point out wat part exactly solved the issue? So I could re edit the answer for easy accordingly

Comment: The problem was in the following

print "?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */<BR>";
echo json_encode($arrCSV,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
print ");";

It seems that there was no need to add those print's before and after the json_encode. All that highstock ohlcv seems to need is the json_encode and the getJSON on the other side.